# How to set Postgres parameters in Play Framework

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, configuration

I am trying to add `temp_file_limit` parameter to my Postgres DB via Play Framework (Version 2.7) configs. I tried adding parameters to `application.conf` as below, but that does not limit temp file size that Postgres DB processes.

`db.postgresql.temp_file_limit = 10KB` - Not working

`temp_file_limit = 10KB` - Not working

`db.default.temp_file_limit = 10KB` - Not working

My current Postgres settings in `application.conf` are as follows (which are working fine).

```
db.postgresql.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
db.postgresql.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
db.postgresql.username = postgres
db.postgresql.password = XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Below are the description of above parameter and other similar parameters of Postgres.
https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/temp_file_limit/

I know we can set those parameters with `SET xxx` queries, but I would like to set it as a config in `application.conf` if possible.

Does anyone know how to configure `temp_file_limit` Postgres parameter in `application.conf` of Play Framework?

Comment: have you tried without `KB`? `db.postgresql.temp_file_limit = 10`

Comment: Thanks @eth4io Unfortunately it also does not limit temp file size that Postgres processes.

Comment: Just an update on this, It still did not work to set that parameter in application.conf, but it is working when I add to it to `postgresql.conf`